# Microsoft InTune seems to be deploying defective an app with defects but works perfect when not deployed from InTune

Tags: intune

I have a mobile app that works perfectly during testing.  However, when it’s deployed from InTune all iOS devices experience one bug (API ‘A’ never gets called), and all Android devices experience a different bug (API ‘B’ never gets called.  However, when we deploy the exact same build from TestFlight, the app works perfect, and when Android devices install the exact same build from a file (the same one we gave InTune) it works perfect.

At first InTune was set to just update the app.  Then we changed it to delete the app and re-install the app, but the problem remained.  Then I had a user manually delete the app on his device removing all data and everything, then he shut down the device for 5 minutes, rebooted, and let InTune re-install.  But the problem continued.  However, as stated before, when installing the exact same build using other means, it worked perfectly.

Can anyone explain this?  I have searched the internet and have not found similar problems.  Also, ChatGPT and Bard were of no help.

Any recommendations on how to move forward on this?

Thank you.